# Is it possible to run NeXTStep as a virtual machine?

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

If I could find a copy of NeXT's operating system, NeXTStep, would it be possible to run it in something like Parallels on a Mac? This Wikipedia page says that [it ran on Intex x86](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/NeXTstep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should be able to get it to run on VMware Fusion

Proof it can be done:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9CfzpYt2Uc

Sources to get it to work:

- [Quick OpenSTEP VMWare Fusion Success](http://www.nextcomputers.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1016&sid=6f0b9858370786de89a0f938beb7dc3e) (Says to follow same steps for NextStep)
- [Here's how to install and configure NeXTSTEP 3.3 on VMware Fusion on an Intel Macintosh running Mac OS X 10.5.](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://www.levenez.com/NeXTSTEP/VMware.html&ei=nAYVTpjxCujw0gHOm4mEDg&sa=X&oi=translate&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CG0Q7gEwBw&prev=/search?q=vmware%2bfusion%2bNextStep&hl=en&safe=active&client=safari&rls=en&prmd=ivnsfd)
- [Install NextStep, OpenStep or OS2 Warp in Fusion](http://communities.vmware.com/message/855157) (Not sure if this one is relevant, but you never know...)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to run OpenStep 4.2 on Parallels, the process is documented extensively here. https://openstep.bfx.re